# Service and Controller to call api with a value in the end of api

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, http-get, angular-controller

I have a service call that I want to pass a value into the function to call the http.get api by id:

```
/home/api/order/1
```

My service looks like this:

```
angular.module("app")
.factory('Service', ['$http', function ($http) {
var urlBase = '/home/api/order/';
Service.getOrderbyorderid = function (orderid) {
        return $http.get(urlBase + orderid)
    };
});
```

What I have tried for my Controller is:

```
getOrderbyorderid ();
        function getOrderbyorderid () {
            $scope.orderid = $routeParams.orderid ;
            console.log($scope.orderid); //Sees ID
            Service.getOrderbyorderid ($scope.orderid )

            .success(function (response) {
                $scope.ordertest = []
                $scope.ordertest = response.data;
                console.log($scope.ordertest ); //Undefined
            })
        };
```

**Question**

Can someone help me in calling the controller right so I can call the api with a specific orderid?

**Error I am getting**

I am getting an undefined when I

```
console.log($scope.ordertest),
```

but I see the id when I

```
console.log($scope.orderid);
```

Comment: This code looks like it should work. What issues are you running into?

Comment: I am getting an undefined when I console.log($scope.ordertest), but I see the id when I console.log($scope.orderid); updating question to reflect error.

Comment: If you inspect the network tab do you see the request being made?

Comment: Thanks @ExplosionPills. the answer below resolved my error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `.then` rather than `.success`. From [the angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http):

> The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been deprecated. Use the standard then method instead. If $httpProvider.useLegacyPromiseExtensions is set to false then these methods will throw $http/legacy error.

The `.success` method destructs the response object for `.then`:

```
Service.getOrderbyorderid($scope.orderid)
// .success(function (data) {
   .then(function (response) {
     $scope.ordertest = response.data;
```